# Perl subroutine - return

Tags: perl, hash

The following code is to make a hash dynamically. If I don't give a `return` statement in the `else` part of the subroutine, I get

```
$VAR1 = {
    'fruit' => { 'apple' => 'skin' } };
```

but If give the `return` statement I get

```
$VAR1 = {
    'fruit' => {
        'apple' => {
            'red' => 'skin'}
        }
    };
```

which is what I want.
What makes this difference. Can someone please educate me.

```
sub construct_hash{
    my ($hash, $value, $head, @tail ) = @_;
    if(@tail){
        $hash = { $head => construct_hash(\%{$hash}, $value, shift @tail, @tail)} ;
    }else{
        $hash->{$head} = $value;
        return $hash;
    }
}
my %h;
my @keys = qw (fruit apple red);
my $value = 'skin';
print Dumper construct_hash(\%h, $value, shift @keys, @keys);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify what to return from a subroutine, Perl returns the value of the last expression evaluated (see [return](http://p3rl.org/return)). In this case, it means the subroutine returns the `$hash->{$head}` in the `else` branch.

Comment: It returns VAR1 = {
    'fruit' => { 'apple' => 'skin' } }; If I dont give 'return' statement, not $value.

Comment: If there is no `return`, the subroutine works as if it had `return $value` there instead.

Comment: Nit: [Technically](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=790129), a scalar assignment evaluates to its LHS, so `$hash->{$head}` is returned, not `$value`.